# Is there an idiom for a loop that executes some block of instructions between iterations? (In Ruby in particular)

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

I often need to do some operations in a loop and some other operations between the iterations.  A simple example would be collecting words from an array into a string, spelled backwards and separated with commas. Is there an idiom or language support for this in any language? (For now i am mostly interested in Ruby.)

I usually do something like

```rb
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
s = ''
n = a.size - 1
i = 0
loop do
  s << a[i].reverse
  break if i == n
  s << ', '
  i += 1
end
```

But i know no way to save this half iteration if using a ruby iterator:

```rb
s = ''
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].each do |w|
  s << w.reverse
  # ???
end
```

Comment: How about nesting them?

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: If a variant of `fold` or `reduce` is unavailable, I'd just initialize `s` and `i` with the results of the first iteration instead of "empty" values.  Then the condition can be moved onto the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the loop-and-a-half problem.  You've described a popular solution.

People who are into functional programming solve many instances of this with a function that is usually called `reduce`, which takes a list and performs a binary operation for every element but the first with the result of the previous calculation, and the next value.  This function is available in Ruby under both the names `inject` and `reduce`.  See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce for more.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will not look very clear inside a template language like ERB or Haml, at least i do not see how to make it clear.

Comment: In haskell, I believe this is called a `fold`

Comment: It seems that this is an inherent fault in all loop constructs that i know: for some reason the default exit point is always put just before the entry point, but i see no reason whatsoever for this to be a common scenario. In my opinion, most loops are "loops-and-a-half".

Comment: @tieTYT Fold is a bit more generalized. In Haskell, it will still append the comma to the first element, because you provided it something to fold into, behind the collection of items being folded. `foldl1` on the other hand, uses the first element of the collection as its start point, and will work the same way `reduce` does in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it in haskell:

```
let a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]  --I've defined my "a" just like you defined it
Data.List.intercalate "," (map reverse a)  --here's the call that does what you want
"oof,rab,zab"  --this is the output
```

The code in the parenthesis calls the `reverse` function on every element of "a" (eg: "foo" becomes "oof").  You take the result of that, and in **another** function you concatenate the elements together with "," in between them.

Here's the key thing to take away here:  Sometimes you have functions that change every element and returns another list (eg: `map` reverses every element, but it still returns a list).  Other times you have functions that take a list and returns one element (eg: `intercalate` will generate *one* string out of the list of strings you pass in).

These are two *separate* steps and your code will be easier to reuse if you keep them separate.

I know this isn't answered in ruby, but I'm hoping it's somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `intercalate` like in @tieTYT's answer in ruby. `Array#reduce` can be used but - e.g. in your example - you have to keep an eye on the order of the elements (reversal of the *accumulator* `memo`).
an example in ruby could look like this:

```
arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "goo"]
puts arr.inspect
red = arr.reduce {|memo, item, err|
    "#{memo == arr.first ? memo.reverse : memo}, #{item.reverse}" 
}
puts red # -> oof, rab, zab, oog
```

your example - joining the elements of an array together into a string - can easily accomplished with `Array#map` followed by `Array#join` (join is like haskell's intercalate, but it does not accept a block in ruby) like:

```
arr.map{|ele| ele.reverse}.join(", ")
```

after your comment to @btilly:
IMHO, both look acceptably clear as one-liners in e.g. erb, though the second one is clearly more readable.

```
<%= arr.reduce{|memo, item| "#{memo == arr.first ? memo.reverse : memo}, #{item.reverse}" } %>
<%= arr.map{|ele| ele.reverse}.join(", ") %>
```

anyway you can always assign the result to a variable upstream.

Comment: Hm, it does not look like the output of ERB will be what i want.  In fact, i would want to output blocks of HTML in a loop, joining them with other blocks, on so that the ERB or Haml template was easily readable.